# soft actor critic algorithm and speech recognition

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to implement SAC algorithm to recognize speech commands. I recorded few words, then converted it to MFCC which refers as state. the actions space is the numbers of words I have. every step I put into the algorithm the MFCC i.e matrix of (40,184), according the matrix I get action i.e probability of certain word. I wondering what is actually the next state?
because now every state is a different word regardless the previous state.

now in my implementation every state is a different word regardless the previous state.